# jQuery selectors with variables

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

How to mix variables with selectors?

I have ID variable.

I want to select image with this id from div #one.

`jQuery('#one img .id')` is the selector. I've tried `$('#one img .'+id)` but doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide a little more of the code and explain what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Edit: Based on your comment below, you would use this:

```
$('#one img.'+id)
```

In your question you have a space between `img` and the `.class`, I've simply removed that so you get `img.className` or `img.'+className`

With the introduction  of [*template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in ECMAScript 2015, you can also do

```
$(`#one img.${id}`)
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing you guys ID is jQuery variable that contains DOM CLASS.

Comment: It's important to note that id must be non-numerical, so do toString() if id is a number.

Answer (score 3):

This might just be a typo or you actually use the `id` variable in a class, but maybe it should be:

```
jQuery('#one img #'+id)
```

Answer (score 3):

`.` is a class selector. Try changing that to a `#`:

```
$('#one img #'+id)
```

Comment: But I want to select a CLASS. I'm trying the way you say but with . instead of #. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

ID's should be unique in your HTML.  So you should be able to select the ID directly without worrying about which DIV it is in.  Since you mention the ID is attached to the `img` tag, then this should be enough.

```
$('#' + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to select img which set with specific class and save this class into id variable within div element with id='one'.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/JGsvh/)

In demo i select img element, clone it, and append to div id=one.