# jquery evaluates string but not variable that has the same value

Tags: jquery

I have en element with the `id ="dk_container_banners[21597][]"`

I remember I have to escape square brackets with double backslashes in jquery selectors

So the value of the x variable is : `"#dk_container_banners\\[21597\\]\\[\\]"`

When I do `$("#dk_container_banners\\[21597\\]\\[\\]")`, I get results

When I do `$(x)`, I get nothing

Let me provide extra details :

`x = ('#dk_container_' + id).replace(/\[/g,'\\\\[').replace(/\]/g,'\\\\]')`

Console says value of x is : `"#dk_container_banners\\[21597\\]\\[\\]"`

After that I do `$(x)` and i get `[]`

If I do `$("#dk_container_banners\\[21597\\]\\[\\]")` I get results

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selectors with variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893436/jquery-selectors-with-variables)

Comment: For me it's working. `x = "#dk_container_banners\\[21597\\]\\[\\]"; $(x);`.

Comment: it is working for me: check this fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/DXD6T/

Comment: Just to let you know, the element ID you have chosen is not actually valid according to HTML4 RFC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html