# How to target element with data attribute as a variable?

Tags: jquery

I am doing this but it's not working

html

```
<a href="#filter-year-y2013" data-filter-value=".y2013">2013</a>
```

jquery

```
var token = document.location.href.split('=')[1];
var attribu = "." + token;
$('a[data-filter-value= attribu]').css("background", "#ddd");
```

This question is different [from this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893436/jquery-selectors-with-variables) as I am not asking to target any selector with variable but a data attribute

Comment: `$('a[data-filter-value="' + attribu +'"]').css("background", "#ddd");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable together with the string selector, try this:

```
$('a[data-filter-value="' + attribu + '"]').css("background", "#ddd");
```

Alternatively you could avoid the concatenation and use `filter()`:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('filter-value') == attribu;
}).css("background", "#ddd");
```

Comment: Thanks man. Why is this question marked as a duplicate if it is not and also none of the answers on that question provides an answer to what I needed? e.g. none says about concatenation as your correct answer here did

Comment: All of the other answers use concatenation - that's what the `$('#one img.' + id)` is in the top answer - where the `id` variable is joined with the string value.

Comment: yes but I do know about that type of concatenation, it's a different way you need to do it in my case e.g. double quotes etc which I did not know and that question did not say it, however, i did found just now, unfortunatly, a correct helping answer on SO, maybe this question should be marked as a duplicate of this instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Comment: Isn't there an XSS vulnerability when passing the variable in this manner?