# What's the proper way to check a checkbox by variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to check a box by value that's equal to the variable but I can't get to work.  Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/OpuLance/n3L8a4zz/4/

It checks all the boxes if I set it to `.val(checkboxValue).prop("checked", "checked");`

I tried `.val() == checkboxValue.prop("checked", "checked");` but that doesn't work

Comment: You are looking for the attribute selector: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/. `.val` either sets the value or returns the value of the first element in the set.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893436/jquery-selectors-with-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** in jQuery:

```
$('input[value="'+checkboxValue+'"]:checkbox').prop("checked", "checked");
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3L8a4zz/5/)**

Comment: You might want to provide a bit more explanation than just "try". Why did the OP's approach not work? What are using to solve the problem? etc.

Comment: `.prop('checked', true)`

Comment: *"use value type selector"* There is no such thing. What you are using as an **attribute selector**.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for giving advice . i changed

Answer (score 0):

you are checking all the check box by `$('input:checkbox').val(checkboxValue).prop("checked", "checked");`
use `$('input[value="'+checkboxValue+'"]:checkbox').prop("checked", "checked");`

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n3L8a4zz/6/)**